# Julia QPDAS: No method matching QuadraticProgram

Tags: methods, error-handling, package, julia

I'm trying to solve a mathematical problem via the package QPDAS. Howevery, every time I call the function to do that, I get the following error:

```
    ERROR: LoadError: MethodError: no method matching QuadraticProgram(::Array{Float64,2}, ::Array{Float64,1}, ::Array{F loat64,2}, ::Array{Float64,1}, ::Array{Float64,1}, ::UniformScaling{Bool}; z=[1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0], P=[5.0 9.0 … -6.0 -10.0; 9.0 17.0 … -8.0 -16.0; … ; -6.0 -8.0 … 17.0 19.0; -10.0 -16.0 … 19.0 25.0], semidefinite=true, ϵ=1.4901161193847656e-8, smartstart=true, scaling=true)
Closest candidates are:
  QuadraticProgram(::MT, ::VT, ::MT, ::VT, ::VT, ::Any; semidefinite, ϵ, smartstart, scaling) where {T, VT<:AbstractArray{T,1}, MT<:AbstractArray{T,2}} at .../.julia/packages/QPDAS/CvMCc/src/quadraticProgram.jl:38 got unsupported keyword arguments "z", "P"
  QuadraticProgram(::MT, ::VT, ::MT, ::VT, ::VT) where {T, VT<:AbstractArray{T,1}, MT<:AbstractArray{T,2}} at .../.julia/packages/QPDAS/CvMCc/src/quadraticProgram.jl:38 got unsupported keyword arguments "z", "P", "semidefinite", "ϵ", "smartstart", "scaling"
  QuadraticProgram(::MT, !Matched::MT, !Matched::VT, ::VT, ::VT, ::PT, !Matched::PFT, !Matched::VT, !Matched::VT, !Matched::Bool, !Matched::VT, !Matched::VT, !Matched::BoxConstrainedQP{T,GT,VT}) where {T, GT<:(QPDAS.AbstractCholeskySpecial{T,MT} where MT), VT<:AbstractArray{T,1}, MT<:AbstractArray{T,2}, PT, PFT} at .../.julia/packages/QPDAS/CvMCc/src/quadraticProgram.jl:22 got unsupported keyword arguments "z", "P", "semidefinite", "ϵ", "smartstart", "scaling"
```

Here is my code:

```
function getSolution(points)    # array of tuples with a tuple and an Int64
    A = [points[i][2] for i=1:length(points)]
    A = reshape(A, 1, length(points))
    b = [0.0 for i=1:length(points)]
    C = diagm(-1 .* ones(length(points)))
    d = b
    M = constructMatrix(points)

    qp = QuadraticProgram(A, b, C, d, z = ones(length(points)), P = M;
            semidefinite = true, ϵ = sqrt(eps(Float64)), smartstart = true, scaling = true)

    sol, val = solve!(qp)
    return sol
end
```

I understand that it says that the types of my variables don't match the ones that are expected by the method QuadraticProgram but I can't figure out in what way. In my understanding it expects the types

```
matrix, vector, matrix, vector, vector, any; semidefinite, ϵ, smartstart, scaling
```

which is what I should have. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The end of the (long) line for the first "Candidate" method says what the problem is:

> got unsupported keyword arguments "z", "P"

In Julia, positional arguments cannot be passed by name, even if they're in the correct position. I.e., in this call

```
    qp = QuadraticProgram(A, b, C, d, z = ones(length(points)), P = M;
        semidefinite = true, ϵ = sqrt(eps(Float64)), smartstart = true, scaling = true)
```

The `z =`  and `P =`  make it so that those are no longer seen as positional arguments. Hence the error, since Julia tries to find keyword arguments in the function definition that match these, and fails in that. (The fact that positional arguments can't be passed via names - even optionally - is one of my minor pet peeves with Julia. The fact that the semi-colon delimiter for keyword arguments is optional and can instead be a comma, also makes the issue non-obvious in this case.)

Changing that line to:

```
qp = QuadraticProgram(A, b, C, d, ones(length(points)), M;
        semidefinite = true, ϵ = sqrt(eps(Float64)), smartstart = true, scaling = true)
```

i.e. just removing `z =`  and `P =`  should fix the issue and call the right method.

Comment: It worked, thanks. For some reason the method call is written with z = and P = in the documentation to the package.